# Как удалить дублирующиеся значения в списке словарей?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список, который возвращается неким API-сервисом в таком виде:

```
l = [{'country': 'USA', 'state': 'Utah', 'town': 'Beaver'}, {'country': 'USA', 'state': 'Utah', 'town': 'Ogden'}, {'country': 'USA', 'state': 'Colorado', 'town': 'Denver'}, {'country': 'USA', 'state': 'Colorado', 'town': 'Salida'}, {'country': 'Brazil', 'state': 'Amazonas', 'town': 'Andarahy'}, {'country': 'Brazil', 'state': 'Amazonas', 'town': 'Tefe'}, {'country': 'Brazil', 'state': 'Roraima', 'town': 'Boa Vista'}, {'country': 'Brazil', 'state': 'Roraima', 'town': 'Ente-Rios'}]
```

Как удалить дублирующийся значения, чтобы по итогу вышел список такого вида:

```
l_1 = [{'country': 'USA', 'state': 'Utah', 'town': 'Beaver'}, { 'town': 'Ogden'}, {'country': 'USA', 'state': 'Colorado', 'town': 'Denver'}, {'town': 'Salida'}, {'country': 'Brazil', 'state': 'Amazonas', 'town': 'Andarahy'}, {town': 'Tefe'}, {'country': 'Brazil', 'state': 'Roraima', 'town': 'Boa Vista'}, {'town': 'Ente-Rios'}]
```

Буду рад любым советам.

Comment: Вы подумайте над первым вариантом от @strawdog. Есть впечатление, что желаемый Вами результат будет, мягко говоря, мало полезным

Comment: Согласен, так будет правильней.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного странный желаемы результат. Не проще ли города из одной и той же провинции держать в виде списка в основном словаре?:

```
import pandas as pd

l = [{'country': 'USA', 'state': 'Utah', 'town': 'Beaver'}, {'country': 'USA', 'state': 'Utah', 'town': 'Ogden'}, {'country': 'USA', 'state': 'Colorado', 'town': 'Denver'}, {'country': 'USA', 'state': 'Colorado', 'town': 'Salida'}, {'country': 'Brazil', 'state': 'Amazonas', 'town': 'Andarahy'}, {'country': 'Brazil', 'state': 'Amazonas', 'town': 'Tefe'}, {'country': 'Brazil', 'state': 'Roraima', 'town': 'Boa Vista'}, {'country': 'Brazil', 'state': 'Roraima', 'town': 'Ente-Rios'}]

df=pd.DataFrame(l)
d = df.groupby(["country", "state"])["town"].apply(lambda x: list(x)).reset_index().to_dict(orient="records")
```

теперь d у вас:

```
[{'country': 'Brazil', 'state': 'Amazonas', 'town': ['Andarahy', 'Tefe']}, {'country': 'Brazil', 'state': 'Roraima', 'town': ['Boa Vista', 'Ente-Rios']}, {'country': 'USA', 'state': 'Colorado', 'town': ['Denver', 'Salida']}, {'country': 'USA', 'state': 'Utah', 'town': ['Beaver', 'Ogden']}]
```

Если нужно вот именно так, как вы написали, то добавляем такой цикл:

```
res = []
for i in d:
    second = i["town"][1]
    i["town"] = i["town"][0]
    res.append(i)
    res.append({"town":second})
```

теперь у вас в res:

```
[{'country': 'Brazil', 'state': 'Amazonas', 'town': 'Andarahy'}, {'town': 'Tefe'}, {'country': 'Brazil', 'state': 'Roraima', 'town': 'Boa Vista'}, {'town': 'Ente-Rios'}, {'country': 'USA', 'state': 'Colorado', 'town': 'Denver'}, {'town': 'Salida'}, {'country': 'USA', 'state': 'Utah', 'town': 'Beaver'}, {'town': 'Ogden'}]
```

Если остановиться на первом варианте, но учесть, что помимо поля "town" могут быть и другие, то сделать можно так:

```
d = df.groupby(["country", "state"])[["town", "code"]].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient="records")).reset_index().to_dict(orient="records")
print(d)
```

получим `d`:

```
{'country': 'Brazil', 'state': 'Amazonas', 0: [{'town': 'Andarahy', 'code': 555}, {'town': 'Tefe', 'code': 666}]}, {'country': 'Brazil', 'state': 'Roraima', 0: [{'town': 'Boa Vista', 'code': 777}, {'town': 'Ente-Rios', 'code': 888}]}, {'country': 'USA', 'state': 'Colorado', 0: [{'town': 'Denver', 'code': 241}, {'town': 'Salida', 'code': 444}]}, {'country': 'USA', 'state': 'Utah', 0: [{'town': 'Beaver', 'code': 124}, {'town': 'Ogden', 'code': 144}]}]​
```

где поля town и другие находятся в каждом словаре списка со своей страной и провинцией под индексом "0"

Comment: Да, спасибо, ваш метод прекрасно работает! Но дело в том, что после ключей 'town' расположены и другие ключи с уникальными значениями (для краткости не стал вставлять полный список пар ключ: значение в вопрос). Например, там после 'town' идет 'code': '12345'. Каким образом я могу применить решение с pandas ко всем таким ключам и значениям, а не только к 'town' ? Спасибо

Comment: в коде добавьте в список нужные поля: `df.groupby(["country", "state"])["town", "code"]` и т. д.

Comment: Сразу так попробовал сделать, но выдает результат такого вида: 
[{'country': 'USA', 'state': 'Utah', 0: ['town', 'code']}, ...]. 

То есть таким образом просто добавляет ключ '0' в каждый словарь в списке, а значением выступает список нужных полей.

Comment: я обновил ответ. и в комментарии я ошибся - список колонок нужно передавать как [["town", "code"]]

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!